# Calculate area enclosed by curve

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Calculate the area of the bounded surface enclosed by the curve $(x+y)^4 = x^2y$ with the help of the coordinate transformation $x = r\cos^2 t, y = r\sin^2 t$.

As I see it the area is unbounded, so this exercise is not solvable, or am I wrong?

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B%28x%2By%29%5E4%3Dx%5E2y%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20-20%2C%201%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%20-1%2C%2020%7D%5D) you can see a plot of the curve.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ImplicitPlot%5B%28x%2By%29%5E4%3Dx%5E2y%2C+%7Bx%2C+-0.01%2C+0.11%7D%5D

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y\geq0$, while $x$ could be also negative.
For $x\geq0$ the graph is given by the following image:

[image]

The relation between $x$ and $y$, with the proposed change of coordinates, becomes
$$
r(t)=\cos^4t\sin^2t
$$
(but note that $r$ and $t$ do not correspond to radius and argument in ordinary polar coordinates).
The area is given, using Gauss-Green formula, by
$$
\int_D dxdy=\int_{\partial D}x dy=-\int_{\partial D}y dx
$$

Taking
\begin{align}
x(t)&=r(t)\cos^2t=\cos^6t\sin^2t\\
y(t)&=r(t)\sin^2t=\cos^4t\sin^4t
\end{align}
and $0\leq t\leq\pi/2$, substituting into the line integral, we get, after some tedious calculation, to 
$$
A=\frac{1}{210}
$$